# Mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inside Triger syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

Thanks Salmon.
I had the same and worked. This is the first time I am using triggers for MySql. I have used triggers for MS Sql server years now and I find its strange in Mysql. It never seems to fire or it is not catching events fast enough. Let me write the real code and explain.

```
DROP trigger if exists sales_ins;
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER sales_ins
AFTER INSERT ON pos_items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE new_am INTEGER;
SET new_am = 0;
If NEW.item_class = 0 Then
    Select
          Sum(ifnull(pos_items.pos_quantity,0)) INTO new_am
        From
             pos_items Right Join pos_invoice On pos_items.inv_number = pos_invoice.inv_number And
            pos_items.branch_id = pos_invoice.branch_id
        Where
            pos_invoice.inv_void_cacel = 0 And pos_items.item_class = 0 And pos_items.item_code = NEW.item_code
        Group By
            pos_items.item_code
        Having
            Not pos_items.item_code Is Null;
    REPLACE INTO item_quantity VALUES (NEW.company_id, NEW.branch_id, NEW.item_code, 
        0, 0, 0,    new_am, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, now(), NEW.rowguid);
ElseIf NEW.item_class = 7 Then
    Select
          Sum(ifnull(pos_items.pos_quantity,0)) INTO new_am
        From
             pos_items Right Join pos_invoice On pos_items.inv_number = pos_invoice.inv_number And
            pos_items.branch_id = pos_invoice.branch_id
        Where
            pos_invoice.inv_void_cacel = 0 And pos_items.item_class = 7 And pos_items.item_code = NEW.item_code
        Group By
            pos_items.item_code
        Having
            Not pos_items.item_code Is Null;
    REPLACE INTO item_quantity VALUES (NEW.company_id, NEW.branch_id, NEW.item_code, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, new_am, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, now(), NEW.rowguid);
End If;
END //
delimiter ;
```

The trouble is, it is not being updated. I will explain the code for clarity.
Once the pos_items table triggers after insert (after insert is used because I need to take this qty to sum too) it will take all transactions sum as sold quantity and update the item_quantity item_sold_qty field or if it is a return, item_salesret_qty field.

What is not happening is the quantity updated is not accurate.
How and where is the error or is it like every create view creates a myisam table, this also is delayed execution. Just I don't understand.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't appear to have set delimiter before the create statement.

Comment: I think you just need a delimiter statement before the trigger.

Comment: Tried with the same error with line number increased.

Comment: It is the delimiter. But I tried with #, $$, //

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sales_ins;
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER sales_ins
AFTER INSERT ON pos_items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO item_quantity (
    company_id,branch_id,item_Code,item_Pur_Qty,item_PurRet_Qty,item_Damaged,
    item_Sold_Qty,item_SalesRet_Qty,item_OtherSales_Ret,item_Stock_From,
    item_Stock_To,item_Stock_Adjust,rem_Sales,item_Transfered,item_Stores_Qty,
    item_MarRets,item_DelPur,item_Samples,item_Tailor,dateguid,rowguid)
VALUES (
    NEW.company_id, NEW.branch_id, NEW.item_code, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, now(), NEW.rowguid)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    item_Sold_Qty = 0, 
    dateguid = now();
END //
delimiter ;
```